# Cannot install Windows

Tags: windows, gparted

I was previously using Ubuntu. Now I need to install  Windows. But Windows does not install.

What if I click the section, does not accept any. It says on the disc has more than one dynamic unit. A disc does not do any action does not delete any of them except

[image]

[image: Windowstan görüntü]

Comment: I suppose that he is trying to install windows on one of the NFTS partitions, but they are too small or damaged.

Comment: dont install windows for Unalloccated

Comment: Is the problem logical vs primary partition types? Try reading [this](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=tr&u=http://askubuntu.com/questions/87908/allocating-drive-space-for-dual-boot&usg=ALkJrhg8BEiY6pc41TZCbGzU2CXcEhOCDg) or [this](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=tr&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fgparted.sourceforge.net%2Ffaq.php&act=url) (translated into Turkish for you).

Comment: Xp Install Eror:STOP C0000221 Unkown Hard Eror \SystemRoot\System32\ntdll.dll

Comment: Windows 7 and 8 install eror:Windows can't be installed to this location.Select anohter partition.

Comment: Windows 7 and 8 Install Eror(anohter partition):Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space.The partition contains one or more dynamic volumes thar are not supported for installition.

Comment: Is the drive formatted into logical partitions? I can't really see well from the screen shot, but I would consider you'd need to delete the first three partitions (The two ntfs and unallocated) and format them as a single PRIMARY sda1. Windows always wants to be on the first primary partition. After a successful install you will also need a GRUB disk or live Ubuntu CD to reinstall GRUB or you will only boot into Windows. I would also suggest that for future installs have a separate /home partition so that if anything ever goes wrong all your documents and data are separate from the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Make a big NTFS partition, maybe to the right of the ext4 partition, because you dont really need ~200 GB for Ubuntu. Just take 75-100 gigs for Windows.

Comment: Okay.But The files are not deleted?Windows is already no disc involvement is not structured.

Comment: I added the above picture of the installation of windows